# Which is better, 'Iberophile', or 'Hispanophile'?

Tags: word-choice, differences

I'm not sure, because according to dictionaries, *Iberophile* isn't a word, but it is the first result on Google for "lover of Spain"

Comment: Does an iberophile love just Spain or do they love the Iberian Peninsula?

Comment: Wait, what just happened to the other question on this topic?

Comment: Also note: No (reputable) dictionary should presume to tell you what *isn't* a word, unless it claimed to contain *every word*. Rather, they tell you that something *is* a word.

Comment: @AndyBonner - the other one was a SWR; this person submitted [a late answer there](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/615271/466641), and has now asked a new clarifying question.

Comment: @Heartspring Ah yes, confusing the "active" and "newest" tabs again.

Comment: [Google nGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=iberophile%2Chispanophile%2Ciberophiles%2Chispanophiles&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) cannot find any examples of *iberophile* in English, which is slightly strange since [Google books](https://www.google.com/search?q=iberophile&lr=lang_en&sca_esv=586125791&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks)  can find some

Comment: Better for what? You need to give us sentence in which the word is to be used, and then state precisely what you intend it to mean — Spain, the Iberian peninsula, Spanish-speaking countries including Latin America, the Spanish language, or what. My bet is that if you describe what you mean it will give you a better alternative than two words, neither of which is in common use.

Comment: @AndyBonner While true, if you check a number of dictionaries and none of them include the word, there's a strong implication it's not a real word. It's unlikely it could escape all their lexicographers' investigations unless it's brand new.